# django form with bootstrap

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to handle a form in django. I am from PHP background, and never used any framework. I used to write all fields of the form by myself in HTML as well as in backend. I used my own methods to validate them.

Now, coming to django, it has model form. But, I want to use bootstrap too in my code. So, I wrote HTML code like this:

```
<div class='form-group'>
 <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_email'>Contact</label>
 <div class='col-md-6'>
   <div class='form-group'>
     <div class='col-md-11'>
       <input class='form-control' id='id_email' placeholder='E-mail' type='text'>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group internal'>
    <div class='col-md-11'>
      <input class='form-control' id='id_phone' placeholder='Phone: (xxx) - xxx xxxx' type='text'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to validate it at backend. My model looks like:

```
class Student(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    enrollment_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    father_income = models.IntegerField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Now, what is the best way to validate above form? 
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Why not use a modelForm and define widgets in the Meta class in your form class? Then you can be sure that your form elements render in a 'bootstrap friendly' way with something like `widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Title',
                    'required': True,
                }
            ),}` and your fields can still be validated by your form class.

Comment: Can you please provide me any documentation regarding this? I am new to django. thanks.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your form, you can use django's model form. You can add some definition to your model form with the `class Meta`:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = [
            'name', 'enrollment_no', # etc... 
        ]
        widgets = { 
            'name': forms.TextInput( attrs={ 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Title', 'required': True, } ),
            'enrollment_no': # etc...
        }

    # you can also override validation/clean/save/etc methods here
```

*Note - because all of your fields are required (according to your model, and because we're using a model form here), django will validate requiring all fields.

Then in your template (assuming you pass the form instance in the context to your template as `form`) you can access each field like so:

```
...
...
<div class='col-md-11'>
    {{ form.name }}
</div>
...
...
```